# Creating a loop with DSharpPlus

Tags: c#, discord

I am trying to create a command with DSharpPlus that will send multiple messages over time.  However, the loop just stops after 5 messages have been sent.  In order to test the fact that it wasn't an error in my code (at least an obvious one) I created another extremely simple loop, and once again, it maxed out at 5.  The test I used is:

```
        [Command("test")]
        public async Task Test(CommandContext ctx)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                await ctx.RespondAsync(i.ToString());
            }
        }
```

So, if this were to wor properly, the bot would send a message for every integer until reaching 50.  However, it stops after the integer of 4.  How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "stop"? Does it throw an exception? If this operation is causing an API call, it may well be throttled, so you are only allowed N interactions per X period of time ... did you check that?

Comment: @Fildor I read through all of the DSharpPlus documentation and did not find anything about a maximum amount of interactions.  And by stop, I mean the loop ends, and no exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Discord has this system in place called "Rate limits". They prevent you from overloading the server with too many requests (the HTTP error you'll receive is 429, too many requests).

To prevent this, DSharpPlus has a system in place with a queue that takes into consideration Discord's rate limit headers to make sure these messages are sent anyway.

Also, I recommend not sending too many messages like this. To prevent these rate limit errors I recommend instead sending as much data as possible in one message instead of separating it into 50 messages send in quick succession.

I hope this answers your question.

That aside, Thanks for using DSharpPlus :)

Comment: Side note that relates to this answer. If you enable the default logger when you're initialising your DiscordClient, you will get a warning show up telling you that the ratelimit has been reached. If you want this set `UseInternalLogHandler` to true. Alternatively, you can subscribe `Client.DebugLogger.LogMessageRecieved` if you want to handle the message yourself.

Comment: @Naamloos If you happen to have a link to some Docs you can add here, that would make the answer even better.

Comment: Discord rate-limit documentation: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits . Dsharpplus enforces a pre-emptive rate-limit that complies with the headers outlined in the documentation. DSharpplus itself does not have documentation on rate-limits as it's specific to Discord's API and not the library itself.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: I literally made dsharpplus...?

Comment: That aside, I did answer the question. I explained why this is expected behavior.